# Precompile riot tag which includes ES6 'import'

Tags: javascript, riot.js

Is there any way to precompile riot.js tag that includes ES6 import syntax like below?

```
<riot-tag>
  <script>
    import Foo from './foo'
    new Foo();
  </script>
</riot-tag>
```

I use gulp and gulp-riot to build tags.

```
gulp.task('tags', () => {
  return gulp.src([`${srcDir}/*`])
    .pipe($.riot({
      type: 'es6'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${destDir}/`));
});
```

Comment: Depends on how your build works. Do you use webpack or something similar?

Comment: @HimmetAvsar Thanks. I use gulp and gulp-riot instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need gulp to transform your ES2015 code into something the riot compiler can understand.

Start by adding an ES2015 compiler to you app:

```
npm install babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Then add your `.babelrc` file, to tell babel what presets to use:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Then gulp should be able to handle it ok from there:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import riot from 'gulp-riot';

gulp.task('tags', () => {
  return gulp.src([`${srcDir}/*`])
    .pipe(riot({
      type: 'es6'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${destDir}/`));
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. The problem i have is not how to compile ES2015-included riot tags  but how to browserify it. In a case you browserify some es6 code which includes 'import' statement, you can browserify it with babelify transform. In my case, the source file is not '.js' but '.tag' so browserify does not work. I tried to browserify js file produced by gulp-riot but it does not work too.

Comment: Check out [riotify](https://github.com/riot/riotify) for compiling tags in browserify.